# Difference between 粒子物理学 and 素粒子物理学

Tags: words, set-phrases

I was trying to tell a Japanese friend that I am studying particle physics, but I didn't know the word for this branch of physics, so I looked it up online.

From what I could find, it should be 粒子物理学, but then he told me that he believes it should be 素粒子物理学 instead.

Why, and what is the difference between the two?

Comment: It is 粒子物理学 in Chinese, 素粒子物理学 in Japanese.

Comment: It's mildly interesting that the branch that deals with fundamental particles (素-粒子) is called particle physics. If I had to guess, 粒子物理学 sounds like physics for grains, like sand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not about difference but about an accepted translation for the subarea of physics.

In different contexts, the English word *particle* may or may not be translated into the Japanese 粒子, but *particle physics* is always [素粒子物理学](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B4%A0%E7%B2%92%E5%AD%90%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E5%AD%A6). Most people who know physics can guess what you mean by 粒子物理学, but it is just unidiomatic.

For another example, solid-state physics would be 固体状態物理学 if literally translated, but the accepted translation is [固体物理学](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%BA%E4%BD%93%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E5%AD%A6).